# Export to Excel Templates in .Net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, export-to-excel

I was given an Excel template and asked to produce 'Export' button which then will export the data to that document.

I have a gridview and currently my export button is working as it should as in export all the data to excel, however now I should work on producing a similar looking template ( not sure how to upload it here) - basically the top two columns in Excel is the title then one row below and column E we have a small table with fields name: Staff ID, Name etc.

This section staff will edit after the data is exported, then below that the gridview data will be populated in.

I found a link that suggested uploading the template to server then using that however i am asked to create a stand alone application and that way will not work for different a branch (they'll have to upload the document to their server and then change the path in the code and thats not ideal).

anyone have any idea on how to design the layout in the code.

Many thanks ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: thank you :) I am not asking for anyone to do the task for me. the export functionality is working is just i need to understand how can i design template in the back end code.. any tutorial / videos / sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: "_any tutorial / videos / sample code will be appreciated_" is precisely one of the question close reasons. Check those help articles I have sent you, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are may libraries that allow you to export to excel and many of them will also allow you to create the document the way you want (merged cells, fills, formulas, etc.) I have use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) but there are others

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) - great .net library with the LGPL v3.0 license. It has everything u asked for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Yes, I know that article. But the Ayman wanted some code how to achieve the result he asked. We don't provide results if the asking person is not providing us some code. I just linked the library which can help him to achieve his goal.

Comment: Providing a link to a library, or asking for such a thing, is off topic and not allowed on SO. Links go dead making such answers useless in the future. The question itself is off topic and shouldn't be answered at all. It will be closed shortly.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I just linked the title, so in the future he can find such as library by its title.

Comment: Again, off topic and this question and your answer will be closed, then deleted, wasting your effort.

Comment: @Rob - a bit harsh in my opinion... The link to EPPlus provided Ayman with the information he needed... in other words it answered his query... the page you linked even say "Provide context for links
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: @Mych Note that the question was closed for just asking for such a thing and it will eventually be deleted along with your answer for the reasons I pointed to. I'm not being harsh. I'm pointing out the rules. You need to read them, too: